# Tokenization - Python Library

Tags: python-3.x

I want to operate on some sensitive datasets.
I am trying to implement tokenization ( Tokenization is the process of replacing sensitive data with unique identification symbols that retain all the essential information about the data without compromising its security. ) for this.

Is there any library available for Tokenization in Python.
If not how could I achieve it?

Comment: Here is one of the library which I found, which is useful and solve my purpose.
https://github.com/emulbreh/pyffx/blob/master/README.rst

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the library which I found, which is useful and solve my purpose. [github.com/emulbreh/pyffx/blob/master/README.rst](http://github.com/emulbreh/pyffx/blob/master/README.rst)